# Nginx Tornado File Upload

Tags: python, file-upload, nginx, tornado

I am trying to upload file via nginx_upload_module 2.2.0. I have nginx 1.0.4 setup as a reverse proxy with a tornado server at the backend.
Below is my nginx.conf :

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;


#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        /var/log/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
index index.html
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
#                  '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

gzip  on;

upstream frontends {
    server 127.0.0.1:8888;
}



server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

# Allow file uploads max 50M for example
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/error.log info;


#POST URLn
    location /upload {
        # Pass altered request body to this location
        upload_pass @after_upload;

        # Store files to this directory
        upload_store /tmp;

        # Allow uploaded files to be read only by user
        upload_store_access user:rw;

        # Set specified fields in request body
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name “$upload_file_name”;
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type “$upload_content_type”;
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path “$upload_tmp_path”;

        # Inform backend about hash and size of a file
        upload_aggregate_form_field “$upload_field_name.md5” “$upload_file_md5”;
        upload_aggregate_form_field “$upload_field_name.size” “$upload_file_size”;

        #upload_pass_form_field “some_hidden_field_i_care_about”;

        upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
    }

location / {
        root   /opt/local/html;
    }


    location @after_upload {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }

}
}
```

I have already tested the setup, and nginx does forward the request to tornado. But when I try to upload the file it gives me a 400: Bad Request http status code. With the tornado log stating that, it's missing the upfile.path in the request. And when I try to go to the folder where nginx should have supposedly stored the uploaded file it isn't there. And hence the 400 error.

Can anyone point why is nginx not storing the file at the specified directory /tmp ?

#### Tornado Log :

> WARNING:root:400 POST /upload (127.0.0.1): Missing argument upfile_path
> WARNING:root:400 POST /upload (127.0.0.1) 2.31ms

#### Nginx Error Log :

> 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2011:13:14:31 +0530] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 400 73 "http://127.0.0.1/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"

#### More verbose Error Log with Info option:

> 2011/07/14 16:17:00 [info] 7369#0: *1 started uploading file "statoverride" to "/tmp/0000000001" (field "upfile", content type "application/octet-stream"), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /upload HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
>
> 2011/07/14 16:17:00 [info] 7369#0: *1 finished uploading file "statoverride" to "/tmp/0000000001", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /upload HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"
>
> 2011/07/14 16:17:00 [info] 7369#0: *1 finished cleanup of file "/tmp/0000000001" after http status 400 while closing request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80

#### More verbose Error Log with Debug option:

```
http://pastebin.com/4NVCdmrj
```

Edit 1:
So, one point that we can infer from the above error log is that, the file is being uploaded by nginx to /tmp but is getting cleaned up subsequently. Don't know why, need help here.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a web application with tornado and nginx-upload-module,and it works.
According to the tornado log you've provided, I guess you can try to change your code

```
self.get_argument('upfile_path')
```

to

### self.get_argument('upload_tmp_path')

nginx did store the file,
but "upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;" this line tells it to cleanup the file, when your application response with the specified HTTP code.

Comment: that doesn't work, gives 500 error status code instead. Can you share your code if possible?

Comment: Can you paste your code, so I can know what's wrong.You can print the self.request.arguments list to check the param that nginx give to you.In my code, I use self.get_argument('files[].name') to get the filename and self.get_argument('files[].path') to get the path.(ps. sorry for my bad English)